# call intercept on android

Tags: android, phone-number, intercept

currently, is call intercept on android possible? to a level where i can get the phone number when a call is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can .... extend  BroadcastReceiver and override onReceive as the following

```
public class CallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            System.out.println(phoneNumber);

            if (phoneNumber != null&& CallService.phoneNumber.equals("ANY_NUMBER_YOU_WANNA_INTERCEPT_ON")) {

                //do what you want to do :)
            }
        }

    }
```

and you will need to add your BroadcastReceiver on the AndroidManifest.xml as the following

```
<receiver android:name=".CallListener" android:permission="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) with a custom [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which gets you `onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)`.

(You'll also need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` in your AndroidManifest.)

Comment: Thanks Ben Williams, I want to get the number when a user make a call. the number where a call is made too.

Comment: I'm not sure you can directly, but if you're listening for phone state changes, you should be able to tell when a call went out and ended, and then immediately `CallLog.Calls` and `getLastOutgoingCall` gives you the last called number.

Comment: tanks again. I will take a look in to that. But what I really want is to get the number while the call is active or when the call button is tabbed.